# multi-language banners for Opencart v2.3

Tags: opencart

I have an Opencart store with multiple languages. Banners can contain only one picture (irrespective of the language chosen), i designed banner for each language.

Opencart v 2.3.0.2

catalog/./view/theme/default/template/extension/module/banner.tpl

```html
<div id="banner<?php echo $module; ?>" class="owl-carousel">
  <?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
  <div class="item">
    <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to manage the banner image files manually (with FTP) but an approach like this could work:

- For each banner you want to display, upload it as usual in admin.
- In the directory where the image is saved, create subdirectories corresponding to the languages you support (for example, "en-gb").
- This code assumes banners are under `catalog/demo/banners`.  So it just adds the path "language_name" under that.
- Modify `catalog/./view/theme/default/template/extension/module/banner.tpl` to look first in the language specific subdirectory in the block where it displays the banner.  In 2.3.0.2, this would look something like:

`<?php 
  foreach ($banners as $banner) {
      $lang = $this->registry->get('language'); 
      if (file_exists($lang . "/" . $banner['image'])) {
          $banner['image'] = str_replace("catalog/demo/banners", "catalog/demo/banners/$lang", $banner['image']);
      }
    }
    ?>`

`<div id="banner<?php echo $module; ?>" class="owl-carousel">
  <?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
  <div class="item">
    <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>`

Comment: Thanks u mr.scott for your interesting , i`m trying but can you help me how to modify  this code in banner.rpl is :    <div id="banner<?php echo $module; ?>" class="owl-carousel">
  <?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
  <div class="item">
    <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
    <?php } ?>

Comment: This is just a `for` loop around what I showed you.  Use the code above in my answer.

Comment: sir i edit my main post and already put it the code can you check please

Comment: OK this should be pretty close to what you need.  Note the assumption that your banners are in `catalog/demo/banners`.

Comment: i dont have this path you mean i must creat it  catalog/demo/banners

Comment: Or change it to reflect what you have.

Comment: sorry sir, i try to edit my code but it appear an error in some line can you please edit the code in my first post and send it to me again

Comment: Dude, I have no idea what the error could be but please stop stalking me and figure out how to debug problems yourself.  Tracking me down on Facebook and by email was a bit much.